# Spacing evenly with md-input-container's and md-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have tried every flex of every kind, layout-wrap, everything angular material I can think of.

I can't figure out how to make these inputs spaced out evenly.

I think the problem is 
that every input is inside of an md-input-container and I can't put a md-datepicker inside of one because then it gives the user two lines for an input.

If someone could let me know how to space these out evenly it really would be awesome!

```
<form name="formData" action="http://localhost:3000/senddata" method="POST">
<md-input-container class="md-block" >
    <label><i class="material-icons">face</i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="$ctrl.name"/>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label><i class="material-icons">explore</i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Zip Code</label>
    <input required type="text" name="zipCode" ng-model="$ctrl.zipCode" ng-minlength="5" pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"/>
    <div ng-messages="formData.zipCode.$error" style="color:red;" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required!</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Minimum length is 5</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="$ctrl.myDate" class="md-block md-datepicker-focused" md-placeholder="Enter date" required md-max-date="$ctrl.maxDate"></md-datepicker>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label><i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp; &nbsp;Search:</label>
    <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="$ctrl.search" required/>
    <div ng-messages="formData.search.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required!</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="formData.$invalid" ng-click="$ctrl.getData()" style="float:right;">Submit
</md-button>
```

Comment: Could you create a Plunker, Fiddle or CodePen example?

Comment: Try putting a md-input-container around the date picker. You need to use latest HEAD. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4233

Comment: column or row layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is nearly two months old but wanted to let you know that this should be fixed in Angular Material 1.1.0, which was officially released 2016-08-14.

[Datepicker didn't used to work well with md-input-container](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4233).  If you're curious, you can also [read the commit with the fix](https://github.com/crisbeto/material/commit/4e4de24c63dcd87cc9d051b4809fbcec5bd1cdcf).